# Redis start server if installed via snap

Tags: redis

I am new to redis and I've just installed it using snap craft. All tutorials say that i can start redis server by typing `redis-server` in terminal. But for me it says that `Command 'redis-server' not found`. Is the process different if installed from snap?

Answer (score 12):

> [SCREENSHOT.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nXzN.png)

**Enabling:**

```
sudo snap enable redis
```

**Starting:**

```
sudo snap start redis
```

**Restarting:**

```
sudo snap restart redis
```

**Stopping:**

```
sudo snap stop redis
```

**Disabling:**

```
sudo snap disable redis
```

**Status services:**

```
sudo snap services
```

**Redis CLI:**

```
redis.cli
```

**Aliasing:**

```
sudo snap alias redis.cli redis-cli
```

**Unaliasing:**

```
sudo snap unalias redis-cli
```

Comment: I know this not related to this question, but your terminal is beautiful and minimalist shape. how did you configured it? 

Answer (score 9):

Start Redis server:

```
sudo snap start redis
```

To run redis-cli copy it to `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
sudo cp /snap/redis/138/usr/bin/redis-cli
redis-cli
```

Comment: I found this works well too and is not (number) specific


sudo cp /snap/redis/current/usr/bin/redis-cli /usr/local/bin